# Matching sequentially repeated brackets with Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

Basically I'm trying to find a series of consecutive repeating patterns using the python with the regex:

```
(X[0-9]+)+
```

For example, give the input string:

```
YYYX4X5Z3X2
```

Get a list of results:

```
["X4X5", "X2"]
```

However I am instead getting:

```
["X5", "X2"]
```

I have tested the regex on regexpal and verified that it is correct however, due to the way python treats "()" I am unable to get the desired result. Can someone advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your capturing group into a non-capturing `(?:...)` group instead ...

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:X[0-9]+)+', 'YYYX4X5Z3X2')
['X4X5', 'X2']
```

Another example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:X[0-9]+)+', 'YYYX4X5Z3X2Z4X6X7X8Z5X9')
['X4X5', 'X2', 'X6X7X8', 'X9']
```

Answer (score 3):

modify your pattern like so

```
((?:X[0-9]+)+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI2bL6/4)

```
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  (?:           # Non Capturing Group
    X           # "X"
    [0-9]       # Character Class [0-9]
    +           # (one or more)(greedy)
  )             # End of Non Capturing Group
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to give in a non-capturing group `(?:<pattern>)` for the first pattern:

```
((?:X[0-9]+)+)
```